# Add new divs with data and remove them on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add new divs when plus sign is clicked and remove them when the cross sign is clicked. This is the [link](http://tinyurl.com/o76bq6e) of an example image.
On the plus sign i want to add new row like with cross sign (In row includes color,size and quantity like 1 and cross sign for remove).
This is my html.

```
<div class="row select_cart">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="new_select">
                <select class="form-control" id="attribute137" name="super_attr[137]">
                    <option>COLOR</option>
                    <option>Lime Black</option>
                    <option>Orange Black</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="new_select">
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option>7</option>
                    <option>8</option>
                    <option>9</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-10">
            <div class="new_select ">
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-2">
            <a class="button delete" title="add unlimited selections"> <img src="images/item_add.png" alt="" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can use clone like this `($("div[id^='myrows']").after($('#myrows').clone());)` or copy code to use same html again and again but issue is that how to attach specific cross sign with each row and remove on click of that.I changed my code little bit.

```
HTML :

 <div class="row2">

                </div>
JS:

    $(".add").click(function(){
           var fld = ' <div class="row select_cart2"> <div class="col-md-12"> <div class="col-sm-4"> <div class="new_select"> <select class="form-control"> <option>COLOR</option> <option>Lime Black</option> <option>Orange Black</option> </select> </div> </div> <div class="col-sm-4"> <div class="new_select"> <select class="form-control"> <option>7</option> <option>8</option> <option>9</option> </select> </div> </div> <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-10"> <div class="new_select "> <select class="form-control"> <option>1</option> <option>2</option> <option>3</option> </select> </div> </div> <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-2"> <a class="button delete" title="add unlimited selections"> <img src="images/item_add.png" alt=""> </a> </div> </div> </div>';

jQuery('.row2').append(fld);

});
    $(".delete").on("click", ".button.delete", function(e){
    $(this).closest(".row.select_cart2").remove();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have those elements in a div like:

```
<div id="container">
…
</div>
```

Then, you can use single event handler to achieve all deletions like this:

```
$("div#container").on("click", ".button.delete", function(e){
    $(this).closest(".row.select_cart").remove();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```js
$('.delete').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row select_cart">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="new_select">
                <select class="form-control" id="attribute137" name="super_attr[137]">
                    <option>COLOR</option>
                    <option>Lime Black</option>
                    <option>Orange Black</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="new_select">
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option>7</option>
                    <option>8</option>
                    <option>9</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-10">
            <div class="new_select ">
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-2">
            <a class="button delete" title="add unlimited selections"> <img src="images/item_add.png" alt="" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row select_cart">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="new_select">
                <select class="form-control" id="attribute137" name="super_attr[137]">
                    <option>COLOR</option>
                    <option>Lime Black</option>
                    <option>Orange Black</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="new_select">
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option>7</option>
                    <option>8</option>
                    <option>9</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-10">
            <div class="new_select ">
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-2">
            <a class="button delete" title="add unlimited selections"> <img src="images/item_add.png" alt="" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row select_cart">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="new_select">
                <select class="form-control" id="attribute137" name="super_attr[137]">
                    <option>COLOR</option>
                    <option>Lime Black</option>
                    <option>Orange Black</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="new_select">
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option>7</option>
                    <option>8</option>
                    <option>9</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-10">
            <div class="new_select ">
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-2">
            <a class="button delete" title="add unlimited selections"> <img src="images/item_add.png" alt="" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row select_cart">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="new_select">
                <select class="form-control" id="attribute137" name="super_attr[137]">
                    <option>COLOR</option>
                    <option>Lime Black</option>
                    <option>Orange Black</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="new_select">
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option>7</option>
                    <option>8</option>
                    <option>9</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-10">
            <div class="new_select ">
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-2">
            <a class="button delete" title="add unlimited selections"> <img src="images/item_add.png" alt="" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you attach and eventListener to the "cross", you will be able to identify the row to which the cross belongs by using -

```
$(".delete").click(function(e){
    var row = $(this).closest(".row");
    row.find("div").remove();
}
```

This should do your work if I have understood your problem correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `parent()` method, The method returns the direct parent element of the selected element.

```
    $('.delete').unbind().bind('click', function(){
        $button = $(this);
        $button.parent().parent().remove();
    });
```

I also created a [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fq02wd4v/4/)

***EDIT***

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x6prfq9b/)

Comment: thanks but i cannot test your demo is that was not compelte.I try this code but no luck can you see whats wrong.its only remove first item and stop removing other ones.`$(".add").click(function(){
        var $button = $('.select_cart').clone();
  $('.select_cart').before($button);
   
});
    $('.delete').unbind().bind('click', function(){
        $button = $(this);
        $button.parent().parent().remove();
    });`

Comment: Its weird it works for me, i just updated the fiddle.

Comment: Maybe i am not understanding you properly, when must the add happen. I just had a quick look at the other answers they also don't have the add.

Comment: I have add my new code with complete js.add works pefrect but delete not works.

Comment: Ok i looked at your code, i updated the fiddle with your JS, but i still cant see the Add button. Fork that fiddle of mine and add the Add buttons html.